# How to slow down the speed of shimmer effect

Tags: android

I have tried the demo of shimmer `FrameLayout` but it goes very fast and I want to slow down the speed of this effect. How to slow down the speed of `shimmer` effect and how to use the properties of this library?

Comment: yes @NileshRathod

Comment: i cant because your answer is not correct @NileshRathod

Comment: can u explain  why

Comment: First of all the attribute is app:duration and not the shimmer:duration and second most imp thing is to the default speed is 1000 so to slow down the speed we must increase the duration @NileshRathod

Comment: check my ans `shimmer:duration="1500" and it is also valid `shimmer:duration` i have tested it in my device

Comment: It shows me this error Error:(10) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shimmer_duration' in package 'com.user.shimmereffectdemo'

Comment: thats why i added this `xmlns:shimmer="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` check my ans again

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use **`app:shimmer_duration="1500"`** to set speed of animation in **`ShimmerFrameLayout`**

Try this

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:shimmer_duration="1500">

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="#dddddd" />

</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `app:duration="1500"` to shimmer `FrameLayout` by default its duration is 1000 so to slow down i increase the duration

```
 <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:duration="1500"
    android:id="@+id/shimmer">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#fff"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:textSize="30dp"
      android:text="Shimmer Effect"/>

</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try defining `app:shimmer_duration` in XML.

e.g. `app:shimmer_duration="1000"`

Comment: Error:(10) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shimmer_duration' in package 'com.user.shimmereffectdemo'

Answer (score 1):

> XML Attr:    `app:shimmer_duration=""`
> You can do the below programmatically -

```
  val builder = Shimmer.AlphaHighlightBuilder()
  builder.setDuration(500L)
  shimmerFrame.setShimmer(builder.build())
```