# How do I set the shimmer layout duration programmatically in java?

Tags: android, user-interface, shimmer

I want to set the shimmer layout duration programmatically in Java.

I have done it in xml, it works, but I want to do it in Java.

Here is the xml code:

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/shimmerFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:shimmer_shape="radial"
    app:shimmer_auto_start="true"
    app:shimmer_duration="800"
    app:shimmer_repeat_mode="restart">

    <include layout="@layout/content_home_activity"/>
</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Fragment{


    private ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerCarousel;
    private static final int shimmerDuration = 1500;

    public HomeActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    shimmerCarousel = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmerFrameLayout);
    }
}
```

I already know how to do it in xml but I want to assign it using Java.

I am looking for a Java or better Kotlin solution.

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63795779/4694013)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example I'm programmatically creating a Shimmer effect in a TextView, setting the duration and a few other things:

```
    //Create shimmer builder
    Shimmer.ColorHighlightBuilder shimmerBuilder = new Shimmer.ColorHighlightBuilder()
                                    .setBaseColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.White))
                                    .setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.White))
                                    .setDuration(1200)
                                    .setIntensity(0.9f)
                                    .setDropoff(0.9f)
                                    .setBaseAlpha(0.6f)
                                    .setHighlightAlpha(1f);
    //Create shimmer
    Shimmer shimmer = shimmerBuilder.build();
    
    //Creating some view to apply the shimmer     
    TextView myTextView = new TextView(context);

    //Creating the shimmer frame layout
    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerContainer = new ShimmerFrameLayout(context);
    shimmerContainer.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    shimmerContainer.addView(myTextView);
    shimmerContainer.setShimmer(shimmer);
    shimmerContainer.showShimmer(true);

    ...

    //Adding the shimmerContainer to myView
    myView.addView(shimmerContainer);
```

You can also use `Shimmer.AlphaHighlightBuilder`. 
To stop the Shimmer use `shimmerContainer.hideShimmer();`
Check the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/javadoc/index.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I read the Shimmer's source, and as I understood, for this version (V 0.4.0), there is no way for developers to set the animations' duration programmatically.

So you should clone the library and change it by yourself, or you can easily use [this library](https://github.com/team-supercharge/ShimmerLayout).