# How do I set the layout for ShimmerLayout programmatically in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, shimmer

> NOTE: My question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519877/how-do-i-set-the-shimmer-layout-programmatically-in-java).

I want to set the layout of `ShimmerLayout` programmatically in Kotlin code. Is that possible to do?

Currently, I can set the layout via XML like this:

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/shimmerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="@{showSimmerBanner ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default=gone}">

         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/shimmerOrientation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_banner" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_banner" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_banner" />

        </LinearLayout>

 </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

Can we set the layout (`@layout/shimmer_banner`) from the Kotlin code?

So, the xml is like this:

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/shimmerLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:visibility="@{showSimmerBanner ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default=gone}"/>
```

And in Kotlin code call this xml like this: `shimmerLayout.set = R.layout.shimmer_banner`, but it doesn't have a function to set layout from Kotlin code programmatically.

How to do that via Kotlin code with still have a `LinearLayout` with `vertical` + can `add more 1 <include> tag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A layout included via an `<include>` tag is just inflated into the parent, so you can simply use a LayoutInflater to do it.

Assuming (from your question) that you have a reference to the shimmer layout as `shimmerLayout`, you can just do:

```kotlin
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(shimmerLayout.context)
inflater.inflate(R.layout.shimmer_banner, shimmerLayout)
```

To change it if you already have views in it, you'd need to do `shimmerLayout.removeAllViews()`, then do the above.

Comment: Hi bro, How can I do if want to add more than 1 an `<include>` tag?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you mean by "add more than 1"?  If you want to include multiple layouts, you could certainly do that by calling `inflate` more than once, but since it's a FrameLayout, they'd just end up on top of each other.  You'd probably want to wrap them in a LinearLayout or something.

Comment: Each include tag is equivalent to an `inflate`, so you could just call `inflate` multiple times, as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: So, in my new XML I just add `ShimmerFrameLayout` and inside it add `LinearLayout`. Then for the `include tag` add from Kotlin code? It's automatic the tag I add from Kotlin code will inside `LinearLayout`?